# where does this Error message coming from in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Whenever I get error messages like in screenshot, I would like to know where does it come from.

I would like to know the code behind that error messages.

I really wounder all the time Where all these error messages come from? I have searched all code files in acumatica website but no luck. I know that some messages are coming from messages class file.

I will really happy if anyone let me know this.

[image]

Comment: More information should be accessible in top right Tools->Trace menu. This specific type of error is related to PXSelector attribute validation and is often thrown by PX.Data assembly.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour is right, this is where I would start. Also, your column looks like a custom field, can you share the DAC attributes of this field?

Answer (score 2):

That specific exception is thrown in the throwNoItem method of PXSelectorAttribute. This code can be found in the App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Data\Descriptor\Attributes\SelctorAttribute.cs file of the website.

Often times doing a search on the directory for the text of the error message isn't successful because Acumatica may not have provided the source code for the class that contains the string. When this is the case it could be beneficial to look at the stack trace and see if that tells you the method that threw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track in looking into the messages class by searching the Source Code files. If you are not getting any results try a smaller subsection of the error. 
Once you find the constant name for the message you can pinpoint areas where the error is raised.

On looking into this a little further trying this myself I see better why your posting this. The closest I get to finding anything is by searching "access rights to this object" and this is the closest result I get is "The specified inventory ID or alternate ID \"{1}\" cannot be found in the system. Please verify whether you have proper access rights to this object."; which is not what you are looking for.

At this point you may want to consider using a decompliation tool such as ILSpy to see if you can get the constant name from the libraries that may not be indexed. Its most likely going to be found in PX.Data.dll

I hope this helps.
Robert

Answer (score 0):

These error messages comes from PXSelectorAttribute.FieldVerifying event handler. This means that the value entered does not match the selector query.